# Prevent progression of pipeline if tag of specified repository is lesser than specified number

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have 2 repositories A & B on gitlab and I make changes on both repositories and tag both of them too.
Can I ensure that repository A's pipeline does not run the last build in its pipeline if the specified tag in Repository B's pipeline has not completed yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for multi project pipeline. This is very well documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html

In this case you can use API's to trigger the pipeline from repository B as the last part of your job.